# Android - how to not make duplicate object

Tags: android, textview, copy, duplicates, spinner

I want to.... if user choose option "set name" in "list" spinner. System make textview called "nama", but if user choose option "set name" again, user doesn't make textview again. Here's my source code :

```
list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            temp = (String) list.getSelectedItem();
            if( temp.compareTo("set name") == 0 )
            {  
               TextView nama = new TextView(this);
               nama.setText("SDSD");
            }
        }
```

Source code at above make user create 'nama' TextView 3 times if user choose option 'set name' three times. If user choose 'set name' 5 times, that textview will be made 5 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this i think its better solution

```
Arraylist<String> exixtList=new ArrayList<String>();

list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        temp = (String) list.getSelectedItem();
        if(!exixtList.contains(temp))
      {

        if( temp.compareTo("set name") == 0 )
        {  
           TextView nama = new TextView(this);
           nama.setText("SDSD");
        }
         exixtList.add(temp);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take help of SharedPreferences.Editor.

Try this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit();
editor.putBoolean("set name", true);
editor.commit();

        list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
            {
                temp = (String) list.getSelectedItem();
                if(temp.compareTo("set name") == 0 && PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getBoolean("set name", true))
                {  
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("set name", false);
                    editor.commit();
                   TextView nama = new TextView(this);
                   nama.setText("SDSD");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean on top right after your class starts Like:

```
public class Activity extends ApplicationContext { 
boolean b=true;
```

and change your condition to this:

```
 if( temp.compareTo("set name") == 0 && b == true)
            {  
               TextView nama = new TextView(this);
               nama.setText("SDSD");
               b=false;                  
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do this is to use flag. set its value to false as a default.

Try this:

```
if( temp.compareTo("set name") == 0 )
            {  
               if(flag==false)
               {
                  TextView nama = new TextView(this);
                  nama.setText("SDSD");
                  flag=true;
               }`enter code here`
               else
               {//do something
               }
            }
}
```

if user first clicks the flag then create a textview and set the flag as true.

Now from second click onwards flag will be checked and go into else part.
:)